# EF: Inserting record to M:N table fails dues to duplicate key value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have two models `Film` and `Rating` that are reflected in database as tables with same name, both of them have Guid Id and are in relation to each other via `FilmRating` table (without model).

To generate FilmRating table, I have in each model list that references the other, eg. `List<Film> RatedFilms` and `List<Rating> Ratings`.

The problem originates when I try to add record to Rating table, that would also add record to FilmRating table. I have following code:

```
 public void AddNewRating(Rating newRating, Film ratedFilm)
    {
        // Add rated film to the rating collection
        if(newRating.RatedFilms == null)
        {
            newRating.RatedFilms = new List<Film>();
        }

        newRating.RatedFilms.Add(ratedFilm);          

        using (var context = new IW5Context())
        {
            context.Ratings.Add(newRating);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

`ratedFilm` is object retrieved from database that represents film to which the rating should be related. `IW5Context` is simply class inheriting DbContext.

It says:

> {"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Film'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Film'. The duplicate key value is (5fd7ab30-b681-46d5-b34b-64afe0d1cfcb).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

From what I understand it tries to insert film to database, while I would expect it only to add records to Rating table and FilmRating table (and maybe check that film exists in Film table).

What should I do in order to get it to work?

Edit - adding Film & Rating models:

```
public class Rating : BaseObject
{
    public double RatingValue { get; set; }

    public string TextRating { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeAdded;

    public List<Film> RatedFilms { get; set; }

}  
public class Film : BaseObject
{
...


  public List<Rating> Ratings
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Id column is type of Guid and is inherited (together with `string Name`) from `BaseObject`.

`AddNewRating` is called from another project (but gets called) via method that is called from ICommand implementation method.

Comment: what does `Film` and `Rating` look like and how are you calling `AddNewRating`.  A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be very helpful, because for now, we kinda have to guess at what scenarios cause your issue

Comment: @SamIam I updated the answer, thank you for suggestions.

Comment: Part of what I wanted to see was how the primary key was defined, and where `newRating` and `ratedFilm` comes from.  If you could include that, it would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the passed `Film` is an existing entity, then you should use [`DbSet<TEntity>.Attach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt136633(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbSet<code>1.Attach(</code>0)) method to let EF not attempt to insert it into the database:

```
using (var context = new IW5Context())
{
    context.Films.Attach(ratedFilm);
    context.Ratings.Add(newRating);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Don't really understand how clean or how sofisticated this is, but it definitively solved my problem. Many thanks.